# Python - Match from one loop to another

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working on simple program and I've got 2 loops. Here is output from first one (`for div in productDivs:`):

```
zalukaj.com/serial-online/81009/lian_yu.html
zalukaj.com/serial-online/80927/missing.html
zalukaj.com/serial-online/80854/honor_thy_fathers.html
```

And here is the output from second loop `for div2 in productDivs:`:

```
Lian Yu
Missing
Honor Thy Fathers
```

I want to make something like this:

```
Lia Yu = zalukaj.com/serial-online/81009/lian_yu.html
Missing = zalukaj.com/serial-online/80927/missing.html
```

How Can I do it ?

Edit:

Full code:

```
link = "https://zalukaj.com/kategoria-serialu/2689,1/arrow_arrow_sezon_5/"
response = requests.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'sezony'})
for div in productDivs:
    linki = div.find('a')['href'][2::]

for div2 in productDivs:
    odcinki = div2.find('a')['title']
```

Comment: what do you mean "make" it? do you want it to be saved as strings? as dicts? what is the use for it? what have you tried?

Comment: you should also post your code.

Comment: "How Can I do it ?" I've heard good things about writing some code.

Comment: You only show the "output" of the loops, but how is that output generated? Are those strings stored in two lists, or maybe already in a single dict? Do corresponding items always appear in the same position, as in your example? And what about the third item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine your two loops. Extract both the link and the title and print them together.

```
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'sezony'})
for div in productDivs:
    linki = div.find('a')['href'][2::]
    odcinki = div.find('a')['title']
    print("%s = %s" % (odcinki, linki))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two loops iterate over two lists:

```
list1 = [
    'zalukaj.com/serial-online/81009/lian_yu.html',
    'zalukaj.com/serial-online/80927/missing.html',
    'zalukaj.com/serial-online/80854/honor_thy_fathers.html'
]

list2 = [
    'Lian Yu',
    'Missing',
    'Honor Thy Fathers'
]
```

I'll use `zip()`:

```
for pair in zip(list1, list2):
    print(pair[1], '=', pair[0])
```

Output:

```
Lian Yu = zalukaj.com/serial-online/81009/lian_yu.html
Missing = zalukaj.com/serial-online/80927/missing.html
Honor Thy Fathers = zalukaj.com/serial-online/80854/honor_thy_fathers.html
```

Answer (score 1):

What about simply storing your loop results in two separated list and running a third loop to display what you want.

```
l1 = [] # your first loop result

# first loop...

l2 = [] # your second loop result

# second loop...

for elem1, elem2 in zip(l1, l2):
    print elem1 + '=' + elem2
```

Here is the zip documentation if you never used this function before : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip.

Comment: That won't give the desired output. Have you checked the output?

Comment: Yes i have tried it and it works just fine. What is going wrong for you?

Comment: Won't it give reversed output?

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the same `productDivs` twice, each time doing 1 action... instead iterate over it just once with both actions, so instead of

```
for div in productDivs:
    linki = div.find('a')['href'][2::]

for div2 in productDivs:
    odcinki = div2.find('a')['title']
```

do this:

```
for div in productDivs:
    linki = div.find('a')['href'][2::]
    odcinki = div.find('a')['title']
    print(odcinki, '=', linki)
```

or if you want to get it as a list of strings, it can be done with one line

```
mylist = [div.find('a')['title'] + ' = ' + div.find('a')['href'][2::] for div in productDivs]
```

or as a dict of keys and values:

```
mydict = {div.find('a')['title']: div.find('a')['href'][2::] for div in productDivs}
```

Say my regards to Felicity Smoak